# How to configure TestNG test method group in pom.xml

Tags: maven, testng, pom.xml

I'm able to run all my tests but i don't know how to configure group in pom.xml and run the test group using maven.

I'm using TestNG frame work but nothing added like testing.xml in pom.xml.

can anyone please help me to make group in pom.xml using testng.. Below is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.automation.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>autotest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>autotest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
            <version>5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<executions> <execution> <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> <goals> 
                    <goal>start-server</goal> </goals> <configuration> <background>true</background> 
                    </configuration> </execution> <execution> <id>stop-selenium</id> <phase>post-integration-test</phase> 
                    <goals> <goal>stop-server</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the groups defined in your cases, and you want to specify the group in your pom, then you can do the following in your pom.  By default, the test phase uses surefire plugin, but you can define the following explicitly to have your groups

```
<plugins>
[...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
      <groups>functest,perftest</groups>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
[...]
```

Comment: Btw why such an old version of Testng?

Comment: Thank you niharika for your response.. but i'm getting null pointer Excedption at this line "studentBrowserDriver.get(stURL);".. If I run the tests without group then it works fine.. Any idea why i'm getting this error when i run with groups

Comment: Either Sturl is null or your studentbrowserdriver is not getting initialized.  Would need more code to help you with that.  Where's the code to initialize the driver?

Comment: I use to run tests using maven but "BeforeMethod and afterMethods" are not invoked when running with maven

Comment: hi if I try to run "functest" group tests then "perftest" group is also running

Answer (score 1):

What I typically do is defining a test cases which I want to run under `src/test/resources/testng` folder, so let's say you will have

- src/test/resources/testng/testSuite1.xml
- src/test/resources/testng/testSuite2.xml

Now, you can run these suits with simple command like

```
mvn verify -Dtestng.suite.xml=src/test/resources/testng/testSuite1.xml
```

Sample TestNG file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="seleniumTest">

<test name="All Components">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="Some group" />
        </run>
    </groups>

    <packages>
        <package name="org.package" />
        <package name="org.package2" />
    </packages>
</test>
```